# Even dirstibution of a small set of random choices into a small set of buckets

Tags: probability, random, uniform-distribution

Is there a way to evenly distribute randomly selected small set of items from a relatively larger set into to a small number of buckets using a hash function?

For ex: Randomly select 20 numbers from 0 to 500 and distribute into 5 buckets such that each bucket has 4 numbers.

Comment: Can you just generate the numbers, shuffle them, and put the first four in the first bucket, the second four in the second bucket, etc.?